# Friction effects on ball motion direction when crossing surfaces edges

Tags: friction

For a ball rolling from a high friction coefficient surface to an adjacent low friction coefficient surface. When the ball crosses the boundary at an angle, I believe it changes angle of velocity, towards the boundary perpendicular direction.

1. Is there a name for this effect?
2. What is the equation?

Comment: Are you sure it changes angle? Why would it do that?

Comment: assuming the surface and the ball aren't perfect shapes, then the left and the right of the ball would go through a phase of having differing frictions, which should turn it.

Comment: Sound like snells law